# No llega el correo con BCc

Tags: php, email, join

Tengo un problema con el envió de correo con copia oculta BCc, en la variable **$to** si me llegan los correos, realizo un `var_dump($row)` para ver el resultado de mi consulta y efectivamente me imprime el correo que le pertenece al usuario, pero nunca llegan los correos en BCc y no marca ningún error.

Resultado de var_dump($row);   `array(2) { [0]=> string(27) "desarrollos.web95@gmail.com" ["email"]=> string(27) "desarrollos.web95@gmail.com" }`

```html
 $envio = "SELECT u.email as email FROM ticket t INNER JOIN user u ON u.id 
 = t.user_id WHERE u.id = t.user_id  order by t.id DESC LIMIT 1 ";
 $resultado = mysqli_query($con,$envio);

 $row = $resultado->fetch_array();

 $cabeceras .= 'From: ' . "Soporte Técnico " . "\r\n";

 if($row==1){
$emailIdUser = $row['email']; 
$cabeceras .= 'BCc: '.$emailIdUser .'\r\n';
}else{
$emailIdUser = "Sin email";
}




 $to = 'soporte.it@gmail.com';


 $cabeceras .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
```

Comment: Cuando añades la cabecera `From` estas perdiendo el `BCc` al no usar `.=`.

Comment: @Sal al agregar `.=` me arroja el siguiente error `Notice: Undefined variable: cabeceras in C:\xampp\htdocs\tickets\action\addticket.php on line 175 `

Comment: Si, por eso deberías inicializar la variable con cadena vacía antes de `if($row==1)` ó iniciarla como lo tenías pero moviendo el `if` después de asignar el `From:`.

Comment: @sal modifique el código, es algo así como lo sugieres?

Comment: La asignación del From puede ir incluso antes del if. Por otro lado tienes que cambiar la asignación de `$emailIdUser`, debes usar `$row` en lugar de `$resultado`, el primero es un registro, el segundo es un resultSet que no contiene la llave `email`.

Comment: @Sal modifique nuevamente mi código con las observaciones que me comentas pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error `Notice: Undefined variable: cabeceras in C:\xampp\htdocs\tickets.usuarios\action\addticket.php on line 164` que es cuando se le asigna el `.=` no consigo que funcione :(

Comment: Al mover la primer asignación antes de `if` ya no necesitas el primer `.`, quítalo y debe funcionar.

Comment: @Sal efectivamente ahí ya no me aparece ningún error, pero sigue sin llegar el correo que se obtiene de mi select, solo me llega el que yo defino en la `$to`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95110/discussion-between-carlos-and-sal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo éstos problemas:

- Dentro del `if` Haces concatenación de `$cabeceras` sin haber declarado la variable previamente.
- Al incluir `Bcc` el `\r\n` debe ir con comillas dobles para que se interprete correctamente la línea del encabezado.
- Después del `if` al hacer `$cabeceras = 'From: ...'` pierdes el Bcc.
- En la asignación de `$emailIdUser` debes usar `$row` en lugar de `$resultado`; el primero es un registro, el segundo es un resultSet que no contiene la llave `email`.

```
    $cabeceras = "From: soporte.it@gmail.com\r\n";
    if($row = $resultado->fetch_array())
       $cabeceras .= 'Bcc: '.$row['email']."\r\n";
    $cabeceras .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias por tu aporte, funciona correctemente. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Has probado a definir la cabecera así? Muestra donde Envias el Correo

```
  $cabecera = 'From: ' . 'soporte.it@gmail.com' . '<' . 'soporte.it@gmail.com'. '>' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $_POST["email"] . "\r\n" .
    'Cc: tumail@dominio.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Bcc: $emailIdUser' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```